# Net stop <service> system error 5 access denied

Tags: command-line, sql-server-2012

From SQL server 2012 I try to do this:

```
DECLARE @COMMAND nvarchar(4000)
SET @COMMAND = 'net stop <servicename>'
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @COMMAND
```

I get system error 5 and Access denied as response

The service account (checked with `whoami`) is added to the administrators, so what else can be wrong?

Comment: when you way 'From SQLServer 2012', do you mean from SQLServer Management Studio (ssms.exe) ?

Comment: Yes, if I put the command(s) in a .bat or .cmd and run that from the OS it's fine. When I try to run it from ssms I get the same error.

Comment: run ssms as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Server 2012 as administrator, and the problem will go away.

Comment: The service account mentioned  has administrator rights.

Comment: Yes, but even so, the runtime has to be performed as administrator. You have to right-click the program, and choose run as administrator, to give the application extra rights. You can see the exact same behavior if you try to do the command in a command prompt window. Even if your user has admin rights, it will not work until you launch the command prompt as administrator. Its an UAC thing.

Comment: In this case, the user running the DB service is unimportant to the issue. The issue is who can CONTROL the service, by starting/stopping/editing the service. SQL Injection attacks would be disastrous if just any old user could execute xp_cmdshell and by virtue of the SQLServers privileged access be able to run arbitrary commands as a server admin.

Answer (score 0):

### Allow non-sysadmin user to execute `xp_cmdshell` from SSMS

*I helped troubleshoot an issue where we needed to grant an app developer access to execute `xp_cmdshell` from within an SSMS session rather than "**Run as**" from **SQL Agent Job** on a non-critical development server without making him a sysadmin on the SQL Server instance.*

### What We Did

**Note:** Domain user account can be replaced by work group account, local machine account, etc.

**Important:** You need to understand the risk of allowing users in your environment to execute OS level commands, and you should only grant this level of permissions to `xp_cmdshell` to those which are trustworthy enough with this level of security with the [proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql) method.

1. Created a new domain user account with a strong password and took note of the username and password. Made sure the account was enabled and the password was set to never expire.
2. Created a new [SQL Server Login](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) tied to the new domain user account we  created.
3. Created a new [proxy credential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql) tied to the domain user account.

   > ```
   > EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account '<Domain>\<NewUser>', '<password>' -- you have to type actual password
   > ```
4. Granted that [SQL Server Login](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) explicit `EXECUTE` access to the system extended stored proc from the `Master` DB named `sys.xp_cmdshell`.

   > ```
   > --see who all has execute access to xp_cmdshell   
   > Use master                      
   > EXEC sp_helprotect 'xp_cmdshell'
   >
   >
   > -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
   > EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
   > RECONFIGURE
   > GO
   >
   > -- Enable the xp_cmdshell procedure
   > EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
   > RECONFIGURE
   > GO
   >
   > -- Grant execute permissions to account
   > GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [<Domain>\<NewUser>]
   > ```
5. Grant the person the uses the `EXECUTE AS` [impersonate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-principal-permissions-transact-sql) permission to the new [SQL Server Login](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql).

   > ```
   > GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[<Domain>\<NewUser>] TO [<Domain>\<UserGrantingExecuteAsUser>]
   > ```
6. Now run the command with the [EXECUTE AS LOGIN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql) and pass the `net stop` command to the `xp_cmdshell` stored procedure. The security principal as listed in step #5 above in the `<Domain>\<UserGrantingExecuteAsUser>` should be that of the person you are running SSMS as security context wise for this task.

   > ```
   > EXECUTE AS LOGIN = '<Domain>\<NewUser>'
   > DECLARE @COMMAND nvarchar(4000)
   > SET @COMMAND = 'net stop <servicename>'
   > EXEC xp_cmdshell @COMMAND
   > REVERT
   > ```

---

### Further Resources

- [sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql)
- [CREATE USER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql)
- [GRANT Server Principal Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-principal-permissions-transact-sql)
- [EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql)